# Android change FragmentActivity to ActionbarActivity with custom title and show overflow

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

I am really confused with custom title and `actionbar` overflow.

Till now I have a `Fragmentactivity` which uses a custom title bar with a big image and 2 more buttons on the title bar. I need now using `ActionBarActivity` to show a action overflow with 2 option menus. `Actionbaractivity` is a subclass of `Fragmentactivity`, but after I using `actionbaractivity`, the initializing in `onCreate()` got problem :

`(equestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);`

> ... error  requestFeature() must be called before adding content .

I have searched `StackOverlow`, but could not found the exact answer. I think it should be a very simple solution, but I can not get it.

```
public class BluetoothChat extends ActionBarActivity implements TimePickerFragment.OnTimeDialogListener
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

    // using custom title to create custom title bar with bdx logo
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.windows_title);
```

Custom title bar theme and layout

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:src="@drawable/bdx_icon_284"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDebug"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBT"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_256"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

style:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">@color/title_color</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/btnConnect"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_bluetooth_32"
          android:title="@string/secure_connect"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/btnModifyName"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/modify_name"
        android:showAsAction="ifroom" />
</menu>
```

Theme.AppCompat theme

```
<style name="mActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/mActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: move getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.windows_title); above setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: @Shahzeb no use, it gets error on line requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.windows_title);
```

instead of:

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.windows_title);
```

Comment: with this change, I got error on   'super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);' 'You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.'

Comment: just replace getActionBar(); to getSupportActionBar();

Comment: You need to change parent of your theme to Theme.AppCompat.* . which targetSDK is set for project ?

Comment: targeted sdk is 17.  with the Theme.AppCompat change above (see edit ) I get the same error.

Comment: Remove <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mActionBar</item>
 from CustomTheme

Comment: it still got problem...  can it be that the custom title can never have a action overflow icon?